# Libtorrent Session_Status not updating

Tags: c++, libtorrent

Im trying to get Session_Status updated but for whatever reason the values of the structure never update, session is started like so:

```
 using namespace libtorrent;
 session* Session;
 session_status* Session_Status;
 session_settings* Session_Settings;

 bool Start_Client_Sess ( )
 {
     using namespace libtorrent;
     Session = new session;
     Session_Status = new session_status;
     Session_Settings = new session_settings;
     Session->settings ( );
     Session->set_settings ( *Session_Settings );

     Session->add_extension ( create_ut_pex_plugin );
     Session->add_extension ( create_ut_metadata_plugin );
     Session->add_extension ( create_lt_trackers_plugin );
     Session->add_extension ( create_smart_ban_plugin );

     Session->start_upnp ( );
     Session->start_natpmp ( );
     Session->start_dht ( );
     Session->start_lsd ( );    

     error_code e;
     Session->listen_on ( std::make_pair ( 6881 , 6889 ) , e );

     if ( e )
     {
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

then on a Windows 1 second timer I'm doing this:

```
 void RunTimer ( )
 {
     using namespace libtorrent;
     Session->status ( );
     if ( Session->is_listening ( ) )
     {
         if ( Session_Status->has_incoming_connections )
         {
             INT x = 2;
             std::cout << x << "\n";
         }
         else
         {
             INT x = 1;
             std::cout << x << "\n";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         INT x = 0;
         std::cout << x << "\n";
     }
 }
```

but no matter what the session is always listening even if the firewall is blocking Libtorrent and there is always connections even if the internet is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to assign the session status to your Session_Status object:

```
*Session_Status = Session->status();
```

I would suggest you don't heap allocate the session_status nor session_settings objects.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's working now but I dont really understand the not heap part, what other part of the functions is wrong?

Comment: Instead of saying: `session_status* Session_Status; Session_Status = new session_status;` you can just say: `session_status Session_Status;` and not have to allocate the object with new, not dereference the pointer with `*`. (and same thing for `session_settings`).