# Libtorrent 1.1.0 issues

Tags: libtorrent

I'm using this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298517/libtorrent-session-status-not-updating) to have the session available globally but the latest updates changed how things are working.

```
using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::weak_ptr;
using libtorrent::aux::session_impl;

using namespace libtorrent;
libtorrent::session* session;
libtorrent::settings_pack* pack;

bool start ( )
{
    pack->set_str ( user_agent, std::string ( "Test " ) + TEST_VERSION_STRING );
    /////
    return true 
}
```

I'm getting user_agent is undefined and after a search of the source I cant see it defined anywhere, libtorrent/settings_pack.hpp is included.

Comment: It's defined right in that header: https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/RC_1_1/include/libtorrent/settings_pack.hpp#L116
what's the question exactly?

Comment: I got it working, needed: pack.set_str ( settings_pack::user_agent , std::string ( "Test " ) + TEST_VERSION_STRING );